# C++ Recursive Function

Tags: c++, function

I am student who just learned c++ not long ago. I have a doubt in mind, for the linked list code below, I don't quite understand the logics behind it, why does the function when it reaches return, it will continue to execute the func1() and cout command ? Isn't it whenever a the programs reaches return it will automatically exits the function and ignore the rest of the blocks below ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Creating a node
class Node {
public:
    string value;
    Node* next;
};

void func1(Node* head) {
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    cout << " " << head->value;
    func1(head->next);


}

int main() {
    Node* head;
    Node* one = NULL;
    Node* two = NULL;
    Node* three = NULL;

    // allocate 3 nodes in the heap
    one = new Node();
    two = new Node();
    three = new Node();

    // Assign value values
    one->value = "A";
    two->value = "B";
    three->value = "C";

    // Connect nodes
    one->next = two;
    two->next = three;
    three->next = NULL;

    func1(one);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is called "tail recursion". The `func1(head->next)` is roughly equal to `head = head->next; goto top_of_function;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what is happening behind the scenes.
Example;
Linked List: head -> A -> B -> C -> NULL;

```
void func1(Node* head) {
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    cout << " " << head->value;
    func1(head->next);
}
```

**Iteration 1:** Head is Not NULL,
So it its **prints A**, now it called **func1(head->next)** recursively.

**Iteration 2:** Head is Not NULL,
So it its **prints B**, now it called **func1(head->next)** recursively.

**Iteration 3:** Head is Not NULL,
So it its **prints C**, now it called **func1(head->next)** recursively.

**Iteration 4:** Head is NULL,
So it it returned from the function and you got the output as A B C.

**Scenario 2:**
Suppose you first write the recursive call and then the print statement head will first reach the end and from then it will print.
**So the output will be C B A**

```
void func1(Node* head) {
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    func1(head->next);
    cout << " " << head->value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I understand well now !

Answer (score 0):

> why does the function when it reaches return, it will continue to execute the func1() and cout command ?

**Only if** the `if` condition is not satisfied, the commands `func1()` and `cout` will be executed. On the other hand if the `if` condition is satisfied, `return` will be executed and `func1()` and `cout` will **not** be executed.

Look at the below example for more clarification:

```
#include <iostream>
void func()
{
    std::cout<<5<<std::endl;
    if(1> 0)
    {
        return ;
    }
    std::cout<<6<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    func();
}
```

Because 1 is greater than 0, the `if` condition is satisfied and the `return` will be executed but `cout<<6;` will **not** be executed.

Now in your example code, you have

```
if (head == NULL)
```

this means **only if** the `head` pointer is `NULL` the `if` will be satisfied and the `return` will be executed but `func1()` and `cout` will not be executed. On the other hand, if the `head` pointer is not NULL then the `if` is not satisfied and so the `return` will not be executed but the `func1()` and `cout` will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

At a certain point in your program, there are 4 invocations of `func1` that are "in progress", with different values for the `head` parameter in each.

The explicit `return` is reached only in the last invocation. Then previous invocation continues, and it reaches the end `}`, which is an implicit return.

Because nothing happens after the recursive call, we call that tail recursion. That kind of recursion is equivalent to a loop.

```
void func1(Node* head) {
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << " " << head->value;
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```